# Why are objects not declared at end of class definition before ; like done for structure in c/c++?

Tags: c++, class, struct

While creating structures, it is common to declare the variables at end of definition like this:

```
struct <name> 
{
  .......
} <variable1>,<variable2>;
```

The same thing works for classes as well such as:

```
class <name>
{
   ......
} <object1>,<object2>;
```

So why is not a common practice to do so? I have never seen such use anywhere. Does this cause some problems? Is it bad practice? If so why and what problems can occur?

Comment: I haven't seen many examples of that first piece of syntax, since that would be useful primarily as a way of declaring variables at file scope and that's not a super common practice. (At least, based on what I've seen!) Do you have some (public) examples you can point at?

Comment: I have seen such examples in books on c and c++ as well as on tutorial websites, for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_structures.htm. but i have never seen such thing when using classes. Even the website I just linked doesn't show that: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm . I don't get why is so?

Comment: "it is common to declare the variables at end of definition like this" - no it isn't - it is very uncommon. You are learning from crappy resources.

Comment: @NeilButterworth but what is wrong with that? and by common i mean at most places it is shown as way of defining variables of structure, but such example is not given for class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I first wrote that as a comment, but it was taking quite a lot of characters and turning into somewhat of an aswer.*

> @NeilButterworth but what is wrong with that? and by common i mean at
>   most places it is shown as way of defining variables of structure, but
>   such example is not given for class.

It's not that there is something wrong with it, it just doesn't have any real-world use aside from allowing you to write simple example codes that holds in a single function (which your references seem to do).

Objects are used, aside from various other things, to write clear, reusable code. If you define the object type in the code where you use it, that means you are not planning on using that, since the definition would not be accessible to other files or modules (or just namespace / scope).

The only way for it to happen is to declare some global variables of class type when declaring/defining that class.. and as you probably already know by then, global variables like that would probably be an anti-pattern.

---

Structures are a bit different, as they are often seen as "plain old data object" even though they are pretty much the same as classes in c++. That means they aren't used as much for code reuse and don't always need to be made public.

Someone could create an anonym structure in a function to hold datas related to each other in a cleaner way than having a dozen of separated variables, for instance. And your syntax could then be used. But doing so with a class would mean having to add the `public:` and be heavier for no reason.

### To sum it up:

It's not that it can't be done, but it would go against pretty much everything the concept of `class` stands for, so we don't do that.

Even with structures, it isn't seen that often outside of structure definitions, but when giving code example, it allows one to show everything he has to without the overhead of having an entire application file structure laying in his book, which is nice and probably why you've seen this.

Answer (score 2):

Lets break down the Answer in two parts:

**Syntax:**

1. As per the syntax wise, I would say it is partially correct, Since you can perfectly create objects of the ***Concrete classes*** only but not of the ***Interface / Abstract class*** which is more common in C++. using the style you have mentioned for defining struct types. Below is the code for class whose objects are being created using the same style.

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   class A
   {
   public:
      A(){std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;}
      void run();
      //virtual void init() = 0; //Will not compile, if init() is uncommented
   }obj1, obj2;

   void A::run()
   {
      std::cout << "Run" << std::endl;
   }
   int main()
   {
      obj1.run();
      return 0;
   }
   ```

**Problem with the above style:**

1. The *life time* and *scope* of the variable becomes attached with class declaration.
2. If the class has been declared in a header file and its object are instantiated / created with the same style. Then, Its unnecessarily creating objects of the class even if you don't need.
3. Most of the times you just need class for creating *pointers* and *references* for it.
4. If I want to either increase or decrease the number of instances / objects of that file, then I need to make changes in the file, where class has been declared. Which can be dangerous and not a good practice if you are going to ship your library or code.
5. This style contradicts *The Open Closed Principle* - *Should be able to extend any classes' behaviors, without modifying the classes..* one of the Oops principle
6. Also almost contradicts, *SRP - The Single Responsibility Principle* -
   *A class should have one, and only one, reason to change.* another Oops principle. 
   As now your class is burdened with the task of creating objects of its own.
7. Most of the classes in C++ are inherited from the Interface / Abstract classes. Which cannot be instantiated and are only used to run time Polymorphism.

These are the some problems which I can see currently, with the style you have mentioned.

**Bottom Line:**
Its a bad style according to me. As it will forbid you from achieving polymorphism.

*You might have seen this kind of syntax, mostly in 'C' code which is meant for embedded programs and low level drive code(For 8051, msp430 etc.,).  They use it mostly, Since they are completely aware of the number of instance of that variable using and the code is mostly while loop.*

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing stopping you from doing it. Technically structs and classes are almost the same except for default visibility of their members, which is public for struct and private for class.

However while struct is most often used for plain old data structures, class is most often used to encapsulate state and behaviour, usually in a polymorphic way. That is just a choice people naturally make, because structs existed in C and were used as POD, while classes were introduced in C++ along with inheritance and member functions. This distinction might be some of the reason why structs are often declared and instantiated instantly, while classes have their declaration exported separately.

Comment: Another difference is that by default a structure inherits bases publicly and a class inherits privately.